# Ubuntu 12.04 hangs after replugging ZTE modem

Tags: 12.04, usb-modem

I have seen a solution to a similar problem: [Ubuntu hangs after replugging the modem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150641/ubuntu-hangs-after-replugging-the-modem)

But what is the solution for a zte modem? I don't think it is the same as that of bcm_wimax.
 Help please.

Answer (score 1):

I have also experienced this problem.

The easiest solution for this is to plug in the ZTE modem to the PC/Laptop when it is off. Then start your PC/Laptop and it will not hang.

But if it again hangs after replugging then Restart your PC/Laptop and use the above method.

There is another solution you may try as explained in this thread, here -> [Ubuntu hangs after replugging the modem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150641/ubuntu-hangs-after-replugging-the-modem)